# How to make a 1 column query by choosing from two columns mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a messaging system (very basic) that has a table like this:

```
**MESSAGE_ID**  **RUSER_ID**    **SUSER_ID**    **MESSAGE_DATA**    **DATE**
```

**RUSER** is the receiving user, and **SUSER** is the sending user. If I wanted to output a query that would output a certain users messages, I would currently do:

**Select * from PRIVATE_MESG where RUSER_ID=$USER_ID or SUSER_ID=$USER_ID**

That would give me all message_id's that are associated with that USER_ID. What I would like, is to create a column that would produce only the **ID** associated with **RUSER_ID** or **SUSER_ID** associated with a specific user. I need it to choose the messages that **RUSER_ID or SUSER_ID** are equal to a **USER_ID** but only display the one that isn't **USER_ID**

I would then like to do a group by the output of that query.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**update** I am not really looking for a message_id, I am just looking for a list of users who that person has written to or received from.

**UPDATE**
Just so everyone knows, I recieved the answer to this question perfectly! I tweaked it later on so that it would also display them by date from newest to oldest. I did this by spliting the DATETIME into DATE and TIME USING the DATE() and TIME() Function. Here was my final query:

```
    SELECT
    IF(RUSER_ID = $USER, SUSER_ID, RUSER_ID) as THE_OTHER_GUY, DATE(DATE) as DAY, TIME(DATE) as TIME
    FROM PRIVATE_MESG
    WHERE RUSER_ID = $USER
OR SUSER_ID = $USER;
group by THE_OTHER_GUY ORDER BY DAY DESC, TIME DESC
```

Hope this helps the next person!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    IF(RUSER_ID = $USER_ID, SUSER_ID, RUSER_ID) as THE_OTHER_GUY
FROM PRIVATE_MESG
WHERE RUSER_ID = $USER_ID
    OR SUSER_ID = $USER_ID;
```

Comment: That does work! Do you know which one will be more efficient? The if or the union?

Comment: The union might be more efficient if you have indexes on RUSER_ID and SUSER_ID but it can become very verbose if you want to compute some other columns :)

Comment: I am a beginner programmer (18 years old), so I throw the term Indexes loosely around not 100% sure the best way to describe them. Those two columns do link back to another table (USER_ACCOUNTS). Would that mean that they are index? Also, your answer really helped me understand more about mysql...Thanks!

Comment: If you explicitly designed them as being FOREIGN KEYS then MySQL also created an INDEX. The documentation is really good on FOREIGN KEYS and INDEX :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUSER_ID FROM PRIVATE_MESG WHERE RUSER_ID=$USER_ID
UNION
SELECT RUSER_ID FROM PRIVATE_MESG WHERE SUSER_ID=$USER_ID
```

It retrieves:
- the list of user IDs who sent messages to $USER_ID
- the list of user IDs who received messages from $USER_ID

And UNION groups the 2 lists in a single result set.

Comment: Doesn't Concat combine them? For example if RUSER=11 and SUSER=12 it would look like this: 1112 ?
I didn't try group_concat just because I figured it would be like Concat
Appreciate the quick response!

Comment: Not exactly, because I am not really looking for a message_id as I am just a list of users who that person has written to or received from.

Comment: That does work! Do you know which one will be more efficient? The if or the union?